# Implementing the spinbutton role - handling touch gestures

Tags: javascript, html, accessibility

The MDN docs on the spinbutton role state that if an input has the role, it should support user gestures for increasing/decreasing values:

> Warning: To change the spinbutton value, touch-based assistive technologies need to respond to user gestures for increasing and decreasing the value by synthesizing key events. Fully test spinbutton widgets using assistive technologies on devices where touch is a primary input mechanism before using the spinbutton role (and all range widgets).

I have searched in lots of places, but haven't been able to find anything specific about how these types of events should be handled. I'm guessing there's at least something similar on stack overflow, but I can't seem to find what types of gestures are supposed to be supported, or if there are any examples of what this may look like.

Comment: Have you implemented up/down arrow support on your spin control, assigned the correct role, and then tested it on mobile ? The paragraph suggests that if you properly respond to up/down arrow, then sweeping up/down should work and that would be the job of screen readers such as VoiceOver to translate that into up/down arrow press. I'm curious on your findings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a set of accessible design patterns from the W3C called the "[ARIA Authoring Practices Guide (APG)](https://www.w3.org/WAI/ARIA/apg/patterns/)".  There's a "[spinbutton](https://www.w3.org/WAI/ARIA/apg/patterns/spinbutton/)" pattern along with an [example](https://www.w3.org/WAI/ARIA/apg/patterns/spinbutton/examples/datepicker-spinbuttons/).

If you run the example on a mobile device, the up and down arrows on top and below the value are buttons that you can tap on. You don't need to use a special gesture.

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

When running a screen reader on the mobile device, you can swipe to the buttons and double tap on them to change the value.